# Text above Image in a Column (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

This is just an example, so I can learn...
I would like to have a small image in the center of the screen... with some Text (centered) above that image? How would I do that?

I've tried this, but the image and the text are really far apart for some reason:

```
body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Text here'
          ),
          Image.asset('assets/image.png')
        ],
      ),
```

**Edit**: *This is what I have so far, just not sure where to put the Column and Text:*

```
body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                colors: [Colors.green, Colors.blue]),
            ),
          child: Center(
            child: Image.asset('assets/image.png')
            ),
          ),
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use a column?

Comment: Not sure where or how to use Columns atm. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, implementing the same in `Column` looks something like this,

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Text here'),
          Image.asset('assets/image.png')
      ],
),
```

[image] [image]

Or else with `Stack`

```
Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Image.asset('assets/image.png'),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text('Text here'),
          ),
      ],
    ),
```

Hope that suits your case!

Answer (score 0):

use Stack widget instead of ListView

```
body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Text here'
          ),
          Image.asset('assets/image.png')
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood me... it's ok... I just wanted it in a Column instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in different way. You can do this using Container

```
Center(
          child: Container(
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/image.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            child: Center(child: Text('Text here')),
          ),
        )
```

or, using stack

```
Stack(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Image.asset('assets/image.png'),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text('Text here'),
            )
          ]
        )
```

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood me... it's ok... I just wanted it in a Column instead.